# Adding flag to cocoapods lib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, compiler-flags

In my project, I include the `JIRAConnect` pod. However, the there are a lot of build-warnings in this project which I am not interested of at the moment. 
For now, after each pod installation/update I need to open the Pods project and add the `-w` flag under `Compile Sources` in `Build Phases`.

Is there some way I can make cocoapods add this automatically? I checked the Pods.xconfig file but can't find anything there. Nothing I found on Google either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to add `inhibit_all_warnings!` in your Podfile. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html) for more information.